# How to find out the startup project of a solution in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015 for C#, a solution always has a project specified as the startup project.

How can I find out the startup project of a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take a look in your solution explorer, you see one project, that is bold:

[image: Project]

That is the one, that is setup as start project

---

You can define also a new one, if you right click on it:

[image: Define new start project]

---

If you have multiple startup projects, you need to go one step further.

Right click your solution on the solution explorer and go to properties. Under Common Properties/Startup Projects you will see an overview about every project and it's auto startup status.

[image: multiple startup projects]

Comment: This is true, but only if there is a single startup project, code I work with every day has 4.

Comment: @Andrew I assume, if more then one start project is defined, you must have seen the screen for multiple start projects.

Comment: Absolutely, but you are only giving half an answer here, since if there are multiple there will not be any bold projects. Not to mention the screen for setting startup projects always gives the complete answer, for single or multiple.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the solution and click on "Set Up StartUp Projects..."